# R: Add predictions to row-wise linear regressions

Tags: r, tidyverse, lm, predict, rowwise

I have three data sets, which one can generate as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Simulate x data

countries = LETTERS[1:3]

mat_x     = matrix(runif(27, 0, 100), nrow = 3)
colnames(mat_x) = 2012:2020
df_x      = bind_cols(country = countries, mat_x)

df_x
# # A tibble: 3 × 10
#   country `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
#   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A         36.2   61.5   15.8   8.52   4.35   24.4   1.74   86.8   15.4
# 2 B         48.3   70.2   96.9  73.1   64.6    74.0  16.0    86.9   80.8
# 3 C         52.7   50.3   70.1  93.7   10.1    44.1  85.1    40.6   54.0

mat_y     = matrix(runif(27, 0, 100), nrow = 3)
colnames(mat_y) <- paste0("Y", 2012:2020)
df_y      = bind_cols(country = countries, mat_y)

df_y
# # A tibble: 3 × 10
#   country Y2012 Y2013 Y2014 Y2015  Y2016 Y2017 Y2018 Y2019 Y2020
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        41.0  86.6  30.6  97.7 41.0    40.1  8.42  76.4  98.0
# 2 B        39.1  12.9  67.9  26.8  0.616  15.6 56.9   49.7  25.8
# 3 C        27.1  82.3  35.0  43.4 24.3    45.9 82.1   82.3  63.3

mat_z     = matrix(runif(27, 0, 100), nrow = 3)
colnames(mat_z) <- paste0("Y", 2021:2029)
df_z      = bind_cols(country = countries, mat_z)

df_z
# # A tibble: 3 × 10
#   country Y2021 Y2022 Y2023 Y2024 Y2025 Y2026 Y2027 Y2028 Y2029
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        31.0  15.0 87.2   50.9  21.0  94.2  90.7  3.32  65.5
# 2 B        42.0  36.2 12.1   63.1  73.8  49.2  40.7 73.9   96.8
# 3 C        96.8  38.0  9.00  67.3  63.7  95.2  51.0 81.7   74.4
```

`df_x` is a response variable, `df_y` is a regressor, and `df_z` are future values of the regressor.

I tried to build nested linear regression models between each row in `df_x` and its corresponding row in `df_y`, as follows:

```
# convert df_x to long format
df_x_long <- 
   df_x %>% 
   pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "year", values_to = "x") %>% 
   mutate(across(year, as.numeric))

head(df_x_long)
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#   country  year     x
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        2012 36.2 
# 2 A        2013 61.5 
# 3 A        2014 15.8 
# 4 A        2015  8.52
# 5 A        2016  4.35
# 6 A        2017 24.4 

# convert df_y to long format
df_y_long <- 
   df_y %>% 
   select(country, starts_with("Y")) %>% 
   pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "year", values_to = "y") %>% 
   mutate(year = as.numeric(gsub("^Y", "", year)))


# join
df_xy_long <- inner_join(df_x_long, df_y_long, by = c("country", "year"))

head(df_xy_long)
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   country  year     x     y
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        2012 88.9   21.2
# 2 A        2013  3.76  24.5
# 3 A        2014 96.2   40.0
# 4 A        2015 26.9   44.6
# 5 A        2016 22.1   27.4
# 6 A        2017 88.7   24.8

# nest and model
df_xy_nested <- 
   df_xy_long %>% 
   group_by(country) %>% 
   nest() %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(model = list(lm(y ~ x, data = data))) %>% 
   ungroup()

head(df_xy_nested)
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   country data             model 
#   <chr>   <list>           <list>
# 1 A       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>  
# 2 B       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>  
# 3 C       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>
```

Now I would like to add predictions for each row (`country`), based on the data in `df_z`, where it gives predictions based on model `lm` for the years `2021` to `2029`, in a way similar to [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html#modelling).

Please help me, any hint or suggestion would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do basically the same thing. You convert `df_z` to long just like you did with `df_x`, nest it and join it to the data, and then use `purrr::map2` (or base `mapply`) to call `predict` on the model and prediction data in each row:

```
library(purrr)
df_z %>% 
  select(country, starts_with("Y")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "year", values_to = "x") %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(gsub("^Y", "", year))) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  nest() %>%
  rename(pred_data = data) %>%
  left_join(df_xy_nested) %>%
  mutate(
    prediction = map2(.x = model, .y = pred_data, predict)
  )
# Joining, by = "country"
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
# # Groups:   country [3]
#   country pred_data        data             model  prediction
#   <chr>   <list>           <list>           <list> <list>    
# 1 A       <tibble [9 × 2]> <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>   <dbl [9]> 
# 2 B       <tibble [9 × 2]> <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>   <dbl [9]> 
# 3 C       <tibble [9 × 2]> <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>   <dbl [9]>
```